# WPF Combo box populate data from mysql database

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, combobox

I am trying to populate a combo box with data but I cant get it work

```
public void fillZone()
    {
        string sql = "select location from zone";
        MySqlDataAdapter zonedapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql,conn);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("zone");
        zonedapter.Fill(dt);                

    }
```

I use fillZone() to get data from mysql and have it stored in a dataTable.I want to populate a combobox named zonecb with data from returned result above, as shown below

```
this.zonecb.ItemsSource = "Location";
this.zonecb.DisplayMemberPath = "Location";
```

my xml is as shown:

```
<ComboBox Canvas.Left="91" Canvas.Top="57" Height="23" Name="zonecb" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will need to acces dt, i dont know if you call your fillzone only for filling combobox but i would suggest:

```
public DataTable fillZone()
{
    string sql = "select location from zone";
    MySqlDataAdapter zonedapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql,conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("zone");
    zonedapter.Fill(dt);                
    return dt;
}

public void fillcombo()
{
     DataTable dt = fillZone();
     foreach (DataCell cell in dt)
     { 
       zonecb.add(cell.Value)
     }
}
```

EDIT:

im using a same kind of method, but ith a postgreSql Database, by changing PgsqlDataAdapter to MySqlDataAdapter this might/should work

```
    public DataSet GetInformation(string str)
    {
        ds = new DataSet("Tables");

        Npgsql.NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new Npgsql.NpgsqlDataAdapter(str, connection);

        da.TableMappings.Add("Table", "Program");
        da.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }// send query to database, get table
```

String str is your Query.

```
    public DataTable GetInfo()
    {
        string Query = "select location from zone";
        DataSet Set = GetInformation(Query);
        return Set.Tables[0];
    }
```

now you got a table wih all the data you need/wanted.

```
   DataTable DT = dBQuery.GetInfo();
   for (int i = 0; i < result.Rows.Count; i++) 
       {          
           zonecd.Items.Add(result.Rows[i].ItemArray[0].ToString()); 
       }
```

now you populated your combobox

Comment: cant fint DataCell namespace. It is in which namespace. Iam getting reference error

Comment: I am using wpf and the application is not web-based. Kindly elaborate